# Name conflict between module and struct in Julia

Tags: julia

I would like to confirm that I can not have a struct named `Test` defined in a module defined as `Test`.

file **main.jl**:

```
# MAIN PROGRAM

include("test.jl")
import .Test

t = Test.Test(3,4)
println(t)
```

file **test.jl**:

```
module Test

        struct Test
            a::Int
            b::Int
        end

end
```

I get:

```
$ /usr/local/julia-1.2.0/bin/julia main.jl
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: invalid redefinition of constant Test
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /usr/home/user/test/test.jl:3
 [2] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1094
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [5] include(::String) at ./client.jl:431
 [6] top-level scope at /usr/home/user/test/main.jl:3
 [7] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [8] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1094
 [9] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [10] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:295
 [11] _start() at ./client.jl:464
in expression starting at /usr/home/user/test/test.jl:3
in expression starting at /usr/home/user/test/main.jl:3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to confirm that I can not have a struct named Test defined in a module defined as Test.

You can not. Each module has a selfbinding, so inside the `Test` module the `Test` name is already taken (by the module itself).

Comment: When you want to have a struct with the "main" name, sometimes the package/module name is plural. For example, the `Color` type can be obtained by loading the `Colors` package.